# Exclude multiple items from SelectList in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a drop-down menu that selects user roles from Startup.cs file.

```
ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin")).ToList(), "Name", "Name");
```

The above code excludes the Admin role. I also want to exclude the Customer role. I am using the code below to do it. It doesn't give me any errors, but it results with all the roles being included in the drop-down menu:

```
ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin") || !u.Name.Contains("Customer")).ToList(), "Name", "Name");
```

How can I exclude more than one item from the SelectList?

Comment: Your second piece of code is almost correct. use && (AND) instead of the || (OR)  you want results that are not admin AND not Customer.

Comment: Try with `ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin") && !u.Name.Contains("Customer")).ToList(), "Name", "Name");` to select any roles without given criteria.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6378815/tetsuya-yamamoto)'s answer which he had posted in Comment.

Try with

```
ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles
.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin") 
&& !u.Name.Contains("Customer")).ToList(), "Name", "Name");
```

to select any roles without given criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also.

```
ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => u.Name != "Admin" && u.Name != "Customer")).ToList(), "Name", "Name");
```